# Pi Pico giving error when trying to enable custom hid device

Tags: pi-pico, micropython, circuitpython

The following is my `boot.py` file. It's a copypaste from [adafruit site](https://learn.adafruit.com/customizing-usb-devices-in-circuitpython/hid-devices).

```
import usb_hid

GAMEPAD_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR = bytes((
    0x05, 0x01,  # Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
    0x09, 0x05,  # Usage (Game Pad)
    0xA1, 0x01,  # Collection (Application)
    0x85, 0x04,  #   Report ID (4)
    0x05, 0x09,  #   Usage Page (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,  #   Usage Minimum (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x10,  #   Usage Maximum (Button 16)
    0x15, 0x00,  #   Logical Minimum (0)
    0x25, 0x01,  #   Logical Maximum (1)
    0x75, 0x01,  #   Report Size (1)
    0x95, 0x10,  #   Report Count (16)
    0x81, 0x02,  #   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
    0x05, 0x01,  #   Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
    0x15, 0x81,  #   Logical Minimum (-127)
    0x25, 0x7F,  #   Logical Maximum (127)
    0x09, 0x30,  #   Usage (X)
    0x09, 0x31,  #   Usage (Y)
    0x09, 0x32,  #   Usage (Z)
    0x09, 0x35,  #   Usage (Rz)
    0x75, 0x08,  #   Report Size (8)
    0x95, 0x04,  #   Report Count (4)
    0x81, 0x02,  #   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
    0xC0,        # End Collection
))

gamepad = usb_hid.Device(
    report_descriptor=GAMEPAD_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR,
    usage_page=0x01,           # Generic Desktop Control
    usage=0x05,                # Gamepad
    report_ids=(4,),           # Descriptor uses report ID 4.
    in_report_lengths=(6,),    # This gamepad sends 6 bytes in its report.
    out_report_lengths=(0,),   # It does not receive any reports.
)

usb_hid.enable((gamepad))
```

I am getting the following error in `boot_out.txt`.

```
Adafruit CircuitPython 7.3.2 on 2022-07-20; Raspberry Pi Pico with rp2040
Board ID:raspberry_pi_pico
boot.py output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boot.py", line 38, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'Device' has no len()
```

I looked into the [documentation](https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/usb_hid/index.html#usb_hid.enable) for `usb_hid.enable()` but I can't figure out why `usb_hid.enable()` is calling `len()` at all on the device? I am passing it  device as a tuple aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I found it rather quickly. A comma after gamepad was needed

```
usb_hid.enable((gamepad,))
```

Maybe this comma will bother someone else in the future